# Scala. Explain {a: Int => Int}

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

I'm beginner in scala.

Anonymous function syntax is clear for me:

`(a: Int) => Int`,

without parentheses: `a: Int => Int` - compile error.

But can somebody explain me purpose of this syntax?

`{a: Int => Int}`

Just another form of anonymous function?

Comment: Not sure where that "compile error" comes from.  This compiles without error: `def blah(a: Int => Int): Int => Int = a`

Comment: when I write val s = a: Int => Int, without parentheses than compile error. but if write val s = {a: Int => Int} - it is ok, so question is what is difference between (a:Int) => Int and {a:Int=>Int)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it is clear to you.

```
(a: Int) => Int
```

this line is not something that someone would actually type. It creates an anonymous function that takes an `Int` named here `a` and returns an object `Int` that is of type `Int.type` and this is companion object of `Int` class.

```
scala> (a: Int) => Int
res0: Int => Int.type = <function1>
```

This is exactly the same thing, just wrapped in useless block that will evaluate to the only expression inside it.

```
{a: Int => Int}
```

To do things properly, to define anonymous function say

```
val fun = (a: Int) => a + 5
```

i.e. put some expression that should be evaluated.

You can also annotate the type of this `val`

```
val fun: Int => Int = _ + 5
```

To define the type of function, you say for example `Int => Int`

```
def apply5(f: Int => Int) = f(5)
```

It seems like you mixed those two concepts (definition of anonymous function and type of function).

Having defined both you can say

```
apply5(fun)
```

Which will have result `10`

I think there is no notable difference between `{a: Int => a + 5}` and `(a: Int) => a + 5`. Actually both are quite common. For example look at defining an action in Play (type of request is annotated just to apply to the example, it is not needed)

```
Action { request: Request[AnyContent] =>
  // some more code
  Ok("")
}
```

Comment: Question actually was what is difference between {a: Int => Int} and (a: Int) => Int syntax. It doesn't matter i this case, let it be {a: Int => a + 5} and (a: Int) => a + 5

Comment: In that case your example of anonymous function was very, well, uncommon and I asumed you are missunderstanding something. Anyway, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is an anonymous function, that takes a single argument `a` of type `Int`, discards it, and returns a scala object `scala.Int` representing the type `Int`.

You can answer questions like this yourself fairly easily with the help of scala repl:

```
scala> val f = { a: Int => Int }
f: Int => Int.type = <function1>
scala> f(1)
res210: Int.type = object scala.Int
```

Comment: Question actually was what is difference between {a: Int => Int} and (a: Int) => Int syntax. It doesn't matter i this case, let it be {a: Int => a + 5} and (a: Int) => a + 5

Comment: It does matter. In the second case there is no difference, in the first one, there is.